# Analogue of AcceptButton property in WPF window class?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, button, acceptbutton

The [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4bcxb43.aspx) class of windows forms has the [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property, which allows certain button to be clicked when a user press Enter. Does the [Window class of WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) has similar feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [IsDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) property on the Button:

```
<Button IsDefault="true">OK</Button>
```

Comment: interesting. Any idea what will happen if I've got two of them in a window?

Comment: Just tried it. Looks like none is clicked, but one of them is focused (probably the first in order of declaration). Setting multiple buttons as Default works fine though, if only one of them is ever enabled (like Start and Cancel for a process).